# Como puedo copiar base de datos en la tarjeta sd?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Como podría copiar una base de datos que yo almacene dentro de mi propia app hacia la tarjeta sd ,por ejemplo si creara una carpeta dentro de `app\src\main\res`  y almacenara la bd en ese directorio, como podría copiarla hacia la tarjeta sd .?

Comment: lo que comentas no est correcto, no puedes crear una base de datos en app\src\main\res si la copias aqui e inservible, no tendría razón copiarla, o esa base de datos no tendría operaciones ?

Comment: a pesar de que respondi, @Jorgesys tienes razon. Yo respondi con el afan de hacer un backup y no de utilizarla....

Comment: yo iba a responder pero mejor decidí hacer una wiki: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79010/como-copiar-una-base-de-datos-o-archivo-desde-el-almacenamiento-interno-al-exte/79011#79011

Answer (score 2):

Puedes acceder a la tarjeta SD de esta manera :

```
File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

A la data de tu aplicacion

```
File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
```

El path de tu base de datos

```
String pathData = "//data//"+getPackageName()+"//databases//"+NOMBRE_BASE_DE_DATOS+"";
```

Crear una variable con el valor del nombre que quieres darle al backup

```
String backupDBPath = "backupdatabase.db";
```

Obtener y/o crear los archivos anteriormente nombrados

```
File currentDB = new File(data, pathData );
File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);
```

Verificar que tu base de datos efectivamente exista, obtener el archivo y crear/traspasar el archivo del backup dentro de la sd.

```
if (currentDB.exists()) {
    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
    dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
    src.close();
    dst.close();
}
```

**Importante**

Debes agregar a tu Manifest el permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` y si estas trabajando con versiones 6.0 o superior, recuerda capturar el permiso y de no haberlo, pedirlo al usuario.

Comment: Como se implementa eso en la apk?

Comment: De donde quieras tu acceder a la tarjeta sd y hacer el backup, como exactamente quieres implementarlo?

Comment: Hola @sioesi yo no es que entienda mucho porque también estoy buscando una solución para poder guardar archivos en la Tarjeta SD, pero creo que con ese código lo único que se consigue es guardar en la tarjeta de memoria interna, que Android la llama externa porque no es donde está el SO, pero en realidad la Tarjeta externa seria la MicroSD extraíble.